# Why isn't this code showing an alert?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here is the code:

```
<html>
<head>  
</head>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#dropdown').on('change', function() 
    {
        alert($("#dropdown").val());
    });
});
</script>

<select id="dropdown" name="dropdown">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
</select>

</body>
</html>
```

You can try a live test here:

http://www.disneypinplace.com/test.php

Comment: There's no ajax in this code.

Comment: What ajax? do you see an error in your console?

Comment: Please check your console next time

Comment: As Pointy stated in his answer, jquery 1.5.1 is really old version of jquery, hence it doesn't support the 'on' method. Update it to the latest one. Also, write your scripts in the '<head>' tag. One more thing that, try to use jsfiddle or some other similar site to that when you are posting sample of your code, instead of your own site.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're importing a too-old copy of jQuery. Your version predates the introduction of the `.on()` API.

Comment: How do I know where to get the latest version?

Comment: Well have you checked the jQuery site? Or for that matter the Google repository itself? You can explicitly ask Google for the latest version.

Comment: http://jquery.com/download/

or

https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide?hl=de

Comment: I didn't realize there was a jquery-latest.min.js link. Thanks.

Comment: I would be careful about using latest as this might come back to bite you in the future. E.g. $.browser was removed in recent versions and plugins and code that used that were broken.. Sticking to a specific version is probably best.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){


$('#dropdown').change( function() 
{
    alert($("#dropdown").val());
});
 });
</script>

<select id="dropdown" name="dropdown">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option> 
</select>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mw9wy/